# XPages - Bind Document Data Source in a embedded Custom Control

Tags: custom-controls, datasource, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages

I created a custom control that is binded to a a Domino Document data source. I embedded it in a page so that I can display it in a Dojo dialog. It has 2 properties: dialogId and docId. The document data source's Document ID property is set to compositeData.docId. In the page, I set the docId property to a viewScope variable, that will be set when an entry in a view is clicked. What I want to accomplish is that the dialog will display the document that the current view entry (that was clicked) represents. But it seems that the compositeData.docId is not set on partial or even full refresh. Is there a way to do this that the custom control will be binded to the document? I need to have this binding so that I can easily do a server-side validation when I submit the dialog. Or if there is another way, can you also put it here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

set the datasource as the document, and then edit mode, then you have a place to compute the doc id, i usually compute the doc id to a viewScope, that i set when i click the item in the repeat control

More details [here](http://blog.hughesconnect.com/?p=62).

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the DocId to be transfered via the custom control parameters rather than a Scope variable. Using the Scope breaks the custom control design principle of being self contained. You can use the yourCC.PropertyMap to actually update a value, so the hand over of the parameter will work - of course your control then needs to be refreshed so the data source is recomputed. Hope that helps.